# Can not run flutter web app on Google Cloud Runner

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, flutter-web, google-cloud-run

I've create a flutter application and I want deploy it to Cloud Run,

And I got the error message :

```
Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information. Logs URL:
```

And I follow the [troubleshooting] https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting

Checked the each 5 point, can not find any solutions

and I noticed the information

```
No active package dhttpd
```

[image]

my Dockerfile is

```
# pull official base image
FROM dart

# set working directory
WORKDIR /flutter

# install app dependencies
RUN dart pub global activate dhttpd

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH $PATH:$HOME/.pub-cache/bin

# add app
COPY build/web ./

EXPOSE 8080

# start app and run at 0.0.0.0
CMD dart pub global run dhttpd --host 0.0.0.0
```

That's all informations I had,
How do I start the image with the Cloud Run ?

**EDIT:**
because I don't know why my image can not get the dhttpd ,
I've used other static web serve, it's worked for me
I've changed the Dockerfile like below

```
# pull official base image
FROM node

# set working directory
WORKDIR /flutter

# install app dependencies
RUN npm i -g serve

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH $PATH:$HOME/.pub-cache/bin

# add app
COPY build/web ./

EXPOSE 8080

# start app and run at 0.0.0.0
CMD serve -p 8080
```

Comment: Can you build and run the container locally without error? If you run it, does it serve on `8080`?

Comment: I built and ran a copy of your Dockerfile using a single `index.html` file. It worked. I've not tried deploying it to Cloud Run. Does your container build and run locally?

Comment: The port to use is $PORT which defaults to 8080. **EXPOSE 8080** is a Docker hint and does nothing in Cloud Run. Try this **CMD dart pub global run dhttpd --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080**

Comment: @DazWilkin Yes, I can build and run the container locally without error.

Comment: @JohnHanley According https://pub.dev/packages/dhttpd I think dhttpd run the web at port defaults to "8080", anyway I tried specific --port=8080 still failure

Comment: Look at the log you included.  **No active package dhttpd**.

Comment: Yes I guess that root cause, so a workaround for me now is use other static web server, bcs I'm a little familiar about nodejs , I chose the serve and it worked 

https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve

and thanks you all

Comment: I think this **is** a Cloud Run issue. I can build and deploy the container locally using e.g. podman (rootless). I can deploy the container to Compute Engine using Container-Optimized OS. I'm unable to deploy the same container image to Cloud Run with the error reported by OP. I suspect (!) the Cloud Run container runtime|sandbox is causing the problem.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/211083676

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the ‘activate’ command for dhttpd in the CMD line, this activates the dhttpd package before it runs. RUN is an image build step, the state of the container after a RUN command will be committed to the container image. CMD is the command the container executes by default when you launch the built image, a Dockerfile will only use the final CMD defined.

Also I changed the port to 8082 but it works in 8080 as well, you can use the one that is best for you. Please try with this Docker File:

```
FROM docker.io/dart

WORKDIR /flutter

ENV PATH $PATH:$HOME/.pub-cache/bin

COPY build/web ./
COPY start.sh ./
EXPOSE 8082

CMD dart pub global activate dhttpd && dart pub global run dhttpd --port=8082 --host=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: it's worked!!
just wondering why it's working on local docker (that "RUN dart pub global activate dhttpd" way)